# Can't Open Ride Python27

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a problem here, I can't open ride.py in Python27
Before I try to open that, I have install this :
1. Python27
 I install this using installer package
2. Robot Framework
 
   `C:\Python27\python -m pip install robotframework`
3. Selenium Library
 
   `C:\Python27\python -m pip install robotframework-selenium2library`
4. wxPython
 
   Download from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/)
5. RIDE
 
    `C:\Python27\python -m pip install robotframework-ride`

But when I open Ride using this syntax

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\python ride.py
```

It show this :

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>python ride.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ride.py", line 20, in <module>
    from robotide import main
ImportError: No module named 'robotide'
```

How can I handle that? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are probably calling a different python from where you installed RIDE.
Try like this:

```
C:\Python27\python -m robotide.__init__
```

Comment: It says `wxPython not found.
You need to install wxPython 2.8.12.1 with unicode support to run RIDE.
wxPython 2.8.12.1 can be downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8
.12.1/`. But I have install wxPython

Comment: That proves you are not calling the same python where you installed wxPython. It is best to have only one python install. Or change the order on PATH environment variable to find the correct `python`. The way you are using is with full path, and it could be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.12.1-py27.exe (32 bit version) . Don't forget remove your old one . 
[wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.12.1-py27.exe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/)

Comment: This may not be true. We need to know if is being used Python 32 or 64 bit first.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed the different version of wxPython & Python installed in your machine.
Make sure you should install the wxPython version same as the python version i.e. Python 2.7.